# Typesetting BiBTeX in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, bibtex

I am wondering if there is a way to print a BiBTeX bibliography in a TikZ node. I am making a huge poster, created as a large TikZ image. I want to include a small bibliography list. Is there a way to print this list in a TikZ node, in the correct layout. I know one could just type in in LaTeX code, but I want the bibliography be easy to maintain without worrying about the official standards.

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am able to get an output with the following code

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
author= {Peter Griffin},
title= {Ahh that hurts},
journal={Drunken Clam Reviews},
year={2001},
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\cite{test}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[draw,fill=blue!50, rounded corners] {\parbox{10cm}{\bibliography{\jobname}}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems that it does not work without some sort of box around \bibliography. Probably because there are blank lines introduced in the bbl file.